# Flutter Error while dropDownButton Select

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i am new in Flutter App developer,so please help. When first time app start then working fine but during select dorpdown value select then getting error using GridView.count[image].

```
   ProductsModel values = snapshot.data;
   List<Product> results = values.data;
    List<List<Inventory>> productList=values.data[index].inventory;
    List<Inventory> productInventoryList=productList[0];       
                  
                         child: DropdownButton<Inventory>(
                          items: productInventoryList.map((proInventory) => 
                          DropdownMenuItem<Inventory>(
                            child: Text(proInventory.label+" "+proInventory.weight),
                            value: proInventory,
                          )).toList(),
                          onChanged: (Inventory value) {
                            setState(() {
                              productInventoryDropDown = value;
                            });
                          },
                          isExpanded: false,
                          value: productInventoryDropDown,
                          hint: productInventoryList[0].weight == null ? Text('Select Weight') : 
                              Text(productInventoryList[0].label+" "+productInventoryList[0].weight,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: add Inventory class code

Comment: child: DropdownButton<Inventory>( items: productList.map((Inventory proInventory) => DropdownMenuItem<Inventory>(child: Text(proInventory.label+" "+proInventory.weight),value: proInventory,)).toList(),onChanged: (Inventory value) { setState(() { inList[index] = value; }); },

Comment: "inventory": [ { "storeId": "5f5c6402db666e253c57866d", "label": "1", "weight": "kg", "price": "100", "default": false },]

Comment: please suggest me what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductsModel values = snapshot.data;
   List<Product> results = values.data;
    List<List<Inventory>> productList=values.data[index].inventory;
    List<Inventory> productInventoryList=productList[0];       
                       productInventoryDropDown=productInventoryList[0]; // this variable must have 1 value of the list because in dart by default there is null value or provide the hintText to `DropdownButton` 
                         child: DropdownButton<Inventory>(
                          items: productInventoryList.map((proInventory) => 
                          DropdownMenuItem<Inventory>(
                            child: Text(proInventory.label+" "+proInventory.weight),
                            value: proInventory,
                          )).toList(),
                          onChanged: (Inventory value) {
                            setState(() {
                              productInventoryDropDown = value;
                            });
                          },
                          isExpanded: false,
                          value: productInventoryDropDown,
                          hint: productInventoryList[0].weight == null ? Text('Select Weight') : 
                              Text(productInventoryList[0].label+" "+productInventoryList[0].weight,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Please do not add "Thanks" to every one of your posts.

Comment: hello @ChristopherMoore I am just following the `code of conduct` from google flutter team.

Comment: Please follow the rules of the site you are currently on, Stack Overflow. The Code of Conduct from the Google Flutter team does not apply here. Additionally, do not use codeblocks for text that is not code.

Comment: ok, @ChristopherMoore Thanks for your suggestions. keep in mind next time.

Comment: Thanks for reply this code is working but how to use in GridView. Current select particular one dropdown value effect all list same value.

Comment: if a selection of one drop-down button depends on another drop-down button then change the state and select the value of child depends on the parent's value using `SetState` or any state management technique like provider or bloc.

Comment: {  "data": [ {  "_id": "5f76975d4401626b89cfc156", "inventory": [ [ { "storeId":"5f5c6402db666e253c57866d", "label": "100", "weight": "ml","price": "49","default": false}]]}]}

Comment: my json value how can i use in dropdown please suggest me.

Comment: Save it to some variable like List<string> and use that variable to show the children of it like variable.map(); use future builder if needed

Comment: child: DropdownButton<Inventory>( items: productList.map((Inventory proInventory) => DropdownMenuItem<Inventory>(child: Text(proInventory.label+" "+proInventory.weight),value: proInventory,)).toList(),onChanged: (Inventory value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  inList[index] = value;
                                });
                              },

Comment: Use DropdownButton onChanged not change value.

Comment: my Invantory JSON value "inventory": [
        {
          "storeId": "5f5c6402db666e253c57866d",
          "label": "1",
          "weight": "kg",
          "price": "100",
          "default": false
        },]

Comment: please suggest me what should i do.